# How to send a list of custom objects over a socket?

Tags: java

```
public class shapeInfo {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int t;
    Color shapeColor;
    int shapeType;
}
```

```
static ArrayList<shapeInfo> shapeStack = new ArrayList<>();
```

How can I send elements of this `ArrayList` over a socket from a client to a server? I tried some structures but all needed one `String` to send.

Comment: I would recommand you looking into object streams.

Comment: Depends. Is your server also running Java? Then look into [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html), but see also [Effective Java](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java-3rd/9780134686097/ch12.xhtml) on serialization. If your server is written in another language, you could export your objects as JSON, XML, Yaml (you'll probably find libraries for these), or whatever works best for your use case. This allows you to support different versions of your data format at the same time (you may or may not need this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use object streams.

In order to do this, `shapeInfo` should be `Serializable`:

```java
public class ShapeInfo implements Serializable{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int t;
    Color shapeColor;
    int shapeType;
}
```

Then, you can send it using an `ObjectOutputStream`:

```java
Socket socket;//your socket
try(ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())){
    oos.writeObject(shapeStack);
}
```

On the other side, you can receive it:

```java
Socket socket;//your socket
try(ObjectInputStream oos=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())){
    shapeStack=(ArrayList<ShapeInfo>)oos.readObject();
}
```

If you don't want to implement `Serializable` or don't want to use object streams, you can also sequentially send all attributes in the `ArrayList` of all objects using `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream`s.

---

**Notes**

Note that class names should be written PascalCase by convention.

You should also need to handle `IOExceptions`.

I did not initialize the socket connection in my example. You need to use an initialized socket connection for it to work.

You should use buffered streams for a better performance.

Variables in objects should be `private` and accessible using getters/setters.